# Multiple Errors when trying to expo prebuild for the first time

Tags: react-native, gradle, build, expo

When i run:
 `npx expo prebuild --clean`
I receive this error:

````
(node:21964) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'C:\Work\SelvaApp\node_modules\chalk\package.json' of 'source'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:21964) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in 'C:\Work\SelvaApp\node_modules\chalk\package.json' of 'source'. Please either fix that or report it to the module author
× Config sync failed
[android.dangerous]: withAndroidDangerousBaseMod: Cannot find module './utils/history'
Require stack:```
Can someone help me?
````

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this because I had a wrong version of android `buildToolsVersion` for my `expo-build-properties` plugin in `app.json`. `npx expo prebuild` worked after I fixed the version.